# tailwindcss highlighting current item in navbar

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, zola

Im trying to highlight item with TailwindCSS and Zola i found this [target](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#target) tag but it doesnt looks its working. Here is my example code:

```
<main>
      <div id="blog" class="target:text-pink-700">
        TEST
      </div>
        <div>
          {% block content %} {% endblock %}
        </div>
        

</main>
```

But it doesnt seems to work:
[image]

I want to use it to highlight current item in navbar. For now default example from flowbite [docs](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/#default-navbar) only highlighting first item. How can i achive changing of highlight to current item? Am i trying to achive it correctly with that "target" tag? Any other better approach of solving this problem without javascript?

Comment: `target` selects the url fragment that is followed by #. Try `127.0.0.1:1111#blog`

Comment: I tested with # instead of paths but this is not supproted by Zola and not redirecting me to proper pages. But even i forced this and putted such path in url bar that "TEST" text didnt change to pink

Comment: Ok something not reloaded i tested it again and that "target" wont help me with it as its not working with static sites like zola (lack of # in paths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tailwind class `target:` will add styles to CSS pseudo-class `:target`. Its styles will be applied if current element ID matches current active target from URL (part after #).

For example, text will be pink in `<div id="blog" class="target:text-pink-700">` if URL contains target to this element: `127.0.0.1:1111/blog#blog`.

Some info and examples of `:target` pseudo-class at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

If you want to apply styles to an active item in a menu with links to different pages (/block, /about, ...) it's better to choose another solution. Compare current URL and links with Zola methods add classes to active menu link. Example from an [zola template](https://github.com/pawroman/zola-theme-terminimal/blob/master/templates/macros/menu.html).

Tailwind can't do it. And Flowbite simply adds different classes to the first element to make it stand out.

Comment: Do you know how those macros templates in zola templates are working? How they are executed after build and deploy STATIC site, is there some hidden javascript?